# Azure Encoding Key

Tags: encoding, key

I use the enstratus management/orchestration platform and I need to add the encoding key from my Azure account into it but I cant seem to find it, can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read all about it here.  The basic gist is you'll have to create your own certificate locally and upload it to your Azure account.

http://docs.enstratius.com/clouds/azure/configuration.html?highlight=azure

Answer (score 0):

For the new version of Enstratus, Dell Cloud Management, follow this procedure:

To add your Amazon account, you need the following information:

```
Account number
Access key
Secret access key
AWS certificate
AWS private key
```

If you don't have that information, follow these instructions to get your AWS account information.

To generate a new access keypair and X.509 certificate via the AWS web console:

```
Navigate to "Security Credentials" under your AWS account name.
Click on Account Identifiers at the bottom to find your AWS Account ID. Copy it to a notepad.
Click on "Create New Access Key". Note that AWS allows only two active keypairs.

Copy the Access Key ID and Secret Access Key.
Click on X-509 Certificates.
Download the Private Key File and X.509 Certificate.
Return to DCM and enter your AWS Account ID, Access Key ID, Secret Access Key, Certificate and Private Key.
Click Connect Cloud Account.
```